# HAML : Img tag inside anchor tag

Tags: html, angularjs, anchor, haml

Here is guy that made a lot of effort:

```
 .picture{:"ng-repeat" => "picture in pictures"}

      %h2 {{picture.title}}

      %a{ :ng-href => "pictures/{{$index}}"}
      %img{:src => "{{picture.url}}"
```

tried to

```
%a{ :ng-href => "pictures/{{$index}}"}
      %img{:src => "{{picture.url}}"
```

and `%a{ :ng-href => "pictures/{{$index}}"}<
          %img{:src => "{{picture.url}}"`>

but nothing works. can't find in haml documentation (these are so bad docs....) answer for my question. Does anyone know how to put  inside  in haml?

Comment: Can you try to explain your question better? I'm not sure what you are asking for.

Comment: img isn't inside the %a tag.

Comment: What is the result? Your image is placed after the atag?

Comment: it depends. In first piece of code its after. in 2nd its error and in 3rd there is error too (during compling, i'm using .hamlc format (rails + angular)

Comment: My mistake was that I used tabs not spaces in new lines. lol

Comment: Can you then answer your question and accept it please

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble properly placing my image inside the anchor, and got the following solution for rails:

Inside your view.html.haml, with embedded rails helpers:

```
= link_to image_tag('name_of_the_asset', alt: 'title'), root_path
```

(`root_path` is using the `url_for` helper but chan be changed for "https://www.someexample.com")